# Entering few integers in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've something like this:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
```

How to do this in one single input line?

Something like `a,b,c,d = int(input())` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really use a [try/except](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) when casting to int but you can use the following:

```
a,b,c,d = (int(input()) for _ in range(4))
```

Demo:

```
In [134]: a,b,c,d = (int(input()) for _ in range(4))
1
2
3
4

In [135]: a,b,c,d
Out[135]: (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

You just need to loop in the range of the numbers you want.

Or get the user to enter the numbers separated by spaces, split on whitespace and [map](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#map) to int:

```
a,b,c,d = map(int,input("Enter four numbers separated by spaces").split())

print(a,b,c,d)
```

Putting it inside a try would be safer:

```
while True:
    try:
        a, b, c, d = map(int, input("Enter four numbers separated by spaces").split())
        break # got four ints so break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input or format")
print(a, b, c, d)
```

You can and should also use a try for the first example:

```
while True:
    try:
        a,b,c,d = (int(input()) for _ in range(4))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
print(a, b, c, d)
```

Comment: @letsdisappear. no worries, you should always really use a try when casting user input

Comment: kay, I'm such a newbie in programming

Comment: @letsdisappear. just means any input that cannot be cast to int or we don't get enough values to unpack won't break the code, we catch the error and ask again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter four numbers, e. g. `1 5 20 3`, then:

```
numbers = input()
a, b, c, d = [int(n) for n in numbers.split()]
```

If you want to enter them with comma, e. g. `1, 5, 20, 3`, then:

```
numbers = input()
a, b, c, d = [int(n) for n in numbers.split(',')
```